# Android Studio Very Slow - Gradle Build Time 11+ mins. Emulator starts the device after 10+mins but doesn't run the app after gradle build

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, performance, gpu, android-studio

PC SPECS
Processor   AMD Ryzen 5 3550H with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx     2.10 GHz
GPU 1 - AMD ATI
GPU 2 - NVIDIA GTX 1650 (Mobile)
Installed RAM   8.00 GB (7.44 GB usable)
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

I have dual booted - Windows & Linux.
Linux - Tried Ubuntu, Fedora 34, Garuda. - Only Garuda felt even more resposive that snappy than my windows. Others just were slower than windows.

It made me feel like garuda is some what optimised for my system as it is heavy too. But it works damn well. - Please share if you can help what could be difference here.

## MAIN ISSUE

But in all distros Android Studio Just didn't seemed to work well.
Takes insane build times & even if it builds then the emulator just doesn't work or install the app correctly.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   You provided no specifics as to the Ubuntu you tried, which product, release, kernel stack chosen etc...

Comment: I think you should lower RAM usage. So if you use GNOME Shell, then switch from it to something like Xfce or MATE. Or if you can - buy more RAM.

Comment: If you are working with 4GB or 8GB RAM then you should increase it. Also switching to SSD will improve the build times significantly. Also if you are building your application for the first time then it may take time to download the libraries needed for that application. I have also worked with Android Studio with 8GB RAM and believe me the RAM should be at least 12GB to get optimal performance with an emulator. Alternatively you can also use your android phone to run your app.

Comment: @guiverc i have installed normal Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: @N0rbert In Android Studio, it uses shows it uses around 500+ out of 1237Mb. So, what do you think about this. And I will try Xfce today.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is available for Servers (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server), for desktops (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop), with various upgrade options (20.04, 20.04.1, 20.04.2 for desktop or server) etc... so Ubuntu 20.04 LTS isn't very specific..  The original ISO used dictates the default hardware stack installed, though if using an ISO that uses `subiquity` you can select it at installl, you can't if you install with other installers provided on other ISOs.  Which did you use?

Comment: @preIdiot Yeah i have 8gigs of RAM. I also have SSD. I have my /(87G), /boot/efi(47G) and swap partitions(15G) in it. And /home in HDD. About the RAM, since it shows it uses just 500+ Mbs out of 1237Mbs - so what's that about. If it requires more i can assign it more by looking at the current scenario right. Yeah i know and can consider only the first time, but it always take 10+ mins to build. But with the same RAM windows is able to perform great, how? Can you share something on this? Yeah i thought of using my phone as my solution for now.

Comment: @guiverc ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64 - this is the ISO file (So yeah DESKTOP, 20.04.2.0)

Comment: @PranavBobde as you said your /home is in HDD, then it means your SDK is located in HDD which means Android Studio is dependent on your HDD instead of SSD. If your Windows OS is located on SSD then this may be the reason for an increase in build time. Also, I can't understand this line "since it shows it uses just 500+ Mbs out of 1237Mbs", who and where?

Comment: @preIdiot oh, okay actually i had a doubt about that, okay i will try to get my home in SSD. And the memory part - The one you can get from: view -> appearance -> Status Bar Widgets -> Memory Indicator.

Comment: @preIdiot It seems SSD was the MAIN FACTOR here. I wasn't aware that it was such a huge key for smooth performance(especially for AS). Tysm. It's working great now.

Comment: @preIdiot After installing Ubuntu in SSD Build Time has reduced and the emulator is working just fine , but now when i try to run my project and try to open my firefox it just becomes too much for the system and the system becomes so slow that i can't even close applications and i have to press and hold power button to shutdown and reboot again. Help plz!